# How to start and shut down itx board with debian at specific times daily

Tags: cron, debian, startup, shutdown

I tried to use a cronjob and crontab -l delivers me the command I saved there:

```
00 20 * * * root /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -s 32000
```

This should shut the board down at 20:00 and turn on 32 000 seconds later. But nothing happens, board is still turned on.

Answer (score 0):

The format you use is appropriate for `/etc/cron.d`files. For normal `cron` records it must be like:

```
00 20 * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -s 32000
```